# Why variables set in for loops do not exist

Tags: batch-file

I write two `for` loops to do data automation. While variables echoed well in each loop, the last step (*data process using a well-written batch*) keeps giving errors that variables set previous do not exist.

The code loops through the subfolders (*q1, q2, etc.*) under the directory. For each subfolder, there is another for loop to set several variables. I echoed three variables fine in loops. 
However, when using a batch called `abc.rb`, the error is `COM_M` does not exist.
Actually, the error is all three variables do not exist.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b ') do (
    echo %%f
    pause
    pushd %%f
    for  %%a in (*.a*.dat) do (
        set COM_DATA=%%a
        echo !COM_DATA!
        set COM_V=%%f\com-v.dat
        echo !COM_V!
        set COM_M=%%f\com-M.dat
        echo !COM_M!
    )
    chdir
    set fig=someA
    set matrix=someB

    rem use a written batch (called abc.rb) to process data
    abc.rb  -a !COM_DATA!  -b !COM_V!  -c !COM_M! -d !fig! -e !matrix!

    popd
)
endlocal
```

Can anyone find any bugs? Thank you!

Comment: Why the need to `dir` then search files? you only need one loop here.

Comment: Also, you did not give the expected results, I do not know what the output of `abc.rb  -a ..` should look like..

Comment: thanks for your reply! abc.rb is used to generate some excel file. But now the three variables cannot be found. The first loop is used to locate each subfolder, q1, q2... and the second is used to set three variables because the name of COM_DATA  are different in each subfolder.

Comment: I'd suggest you try adding `echo abc.rb -a...` before `CALL abc.rb` (in place of simply executing `abc.rb`). Without seeing `abc.rb.bat` it's guessing, but if you are expecting `com_data` to be established when `abc.rb` is executed, then mayhap the `call` will fix that, but then there's no real point in delivering it as a parameter which `abc.rb.bat` would see as `%2`. The `for %%a` seems to be a massive waste of time - all it will do is establish `com_data` as the last `*.a*.dat` file in the directory

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the need to `pushd` into the dir, but as far as I can see, there is only a need for a single `for` loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "fig=someA"
set "matrix=someB"
for  /R %%a in (*.a*.dat) do (
    set "COM_DATA=%%a"
    echo !COM_DATA!
    set "COM_V=%%~dpacom-v.dat
    echo !COM_V!
    set COM_M=%%~dpacom-M.dat
    echo !COM_M!
    rem If abc.rb is is NOT a windows batch file, remove call below
    call abc.rb  -a "!COM_DATA!"  -b "!COM_V!"  -c "!COM_M!" -d !fig! -e !matrix!
)
```

If you require the `pushd` (which I doubt)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "fig=someA"
set "matrix=someB"
for  /R %%a in (*.a*.dat) do (
    pushd "%%~dpa"
    set "COM_DATA=%%a"
    echo !COM_DATA!
    set "COM_V=%%~dpacom-v.dat"
    echo !COM_V!
    set "COM_M=%%~dpacom-M.dat"
    echo !COM_M!
    rem If abc.rb is is NOT a windows batch file, remove call below
    call abc.rb  -a "!COM_DATA!"  -b "!COM_V!"  -c "!COM_M!" -d !fig! -e !matrix!
    popd
)
```

The double quotes will help if the paths have whitespace, if your program has an issue with them, then you can remove them: `abc.rb  -a !COM_DATA!  -b !COM_V!  -c !COM_M! -d !fig! -e !matrix!`

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "fig=someA"
set "matrix=someB"
set "COM_V=com-v.dat"
set "COM_M=com-M.dat"

for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b') do (
    echo %%f
    pause
    if exist "%%~f\*.a*.dat" (
        pushd "%%~f" && (
            for  %%a in (*.a*.dat) do (
                set "COM_DATA=%%~a"
                echo !COM_DATA!
            )
            chdir

            rem use a written batch called abc.rb to process data
            call abc.rb  -a "!COM_DATA!"  -b "!COM_V!"  -c "!COM_M!" -d "!fig!" -e "!matrix!"

            popd
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

Issues:

1. If the nested `for` loop finds no files with the matched pattern of `*.a*.dat`, then the variables `COM_DATA`, `COM_V` and `COM_M` may not be defined or updated with a newer value.
2. Value of `COM_DATA` is a filename. Values of `COM_V` and `COM_M` is the parent folder name and filename, which is inconsistent. Based on the current directory, I would consider filenames as correct. This means that `COM_V` and `COM_M` never need to change.
3. If `abc.rb` is a batch-file, then you need to use `call` for the interpreter to return control back to the main script.

Changes:

1. Test if the file pattern exists, and run the code within the code block if true.
2. `COM_V` and `COM_M` moved out of the `for` loop as values never change.
3. Calling `abc.rb` as being a batch-file.
4. `fig` and `matrix` moved out of the `for` loop as values never change.
5. Double quote setting of variables and use of variables to avoid issues with spaces, special characters etc.
6. `pushd && (` ensures the code within the parentheses is run only on success of changing directory.
7. Removed parentheses in the `rem` line. They may not cause a problem, though `rem` lines are parsed and can cause a syntax error. Suggest avoiding special characters in `rem` lines unless you intend to debug.